# Browser-friendly popup windows that don't get blocked (for a help window) - jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery

I've been tasked with making our help section open in a new window which *isn't* blocked by any of the major browsers' anti popup behaviour.  My spec is 'to make it like the one on the salesforce website'.  haha.  (The salesforce site is login only i'm afraid so i can't even show you it.)

Anyway, before i tried to reverse engineer that site i thought i'd ask here, thinking that there may be a jquery plugin for this, for example, and that generally this problem would have been solved already by smarter people than me.

Any advice welcome - max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), it comes in many flavours and you can put whatever you want in it, if you absolutely have to you can even use it as an [iframe](http://elijahmanor.com/webdevdotnet/post/jQuery-UI-Dialog-w-Resizable-iFrame.aspx) pop-up.

The dialog works by showing and hiding a div which is positioned on top over all other elements, there is little chance a pop-up blocker will cause any problems, but it does require javascript to be turned on. If javascript was turned off you'd have to use a bit of graceful degradation to maintain it's usability.

Comment: thanks ILMV but i want a totally seperate browser window (eg that can be dragged to one side of the main window), not a floating-in-the-browser dialog.  cheers tho

Comment: So you want a pop-up that doesn't get killed by a pop-up blocker... sorry, but if that existed you think it wouldn't be used for spamvertising everywhere? If it we me I'd rethink not using a standard pop-up... even if you were requested to do so.

Comment: yeah that's what i thought, ie if this was possible we'd all be getting them all the time.  i'm trying to persuade my boss to go with jqueryui dialog.  i actually think it's better anyway (after a bit of thought) as it stays visible while you interact with the page behind, so is great for tutorials etc.

Comment: Just as a followup i went down the jqueryui dialog route and it's worked out really well. thanks again for the pointer. max

Comment: No problem Max, used it for similar purposes and found it to be a very competent solution :-)